# find files with ACLs set

Tags: linux, bash, find, acl

How can I find all files with some extended ACLs set, i.e. those with a little `+` at the end of the permission flags shown by `ls -l`.

I could not find a corresponding flag for `find`. My naive approach would be a `find` combined with `ls -l` and a `grep`. But I don't think this is nice.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`getfacl` can dump ACLs recursively, and it has a `--skip-base` option for ignoring files without ACLs.

```
getfacl -R -s -p /directory | sed -n 's/^# file: //p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl version:

```
getfacl -R -p -s  / | perl -wn -e ' if (/^# file/) { s|^# file: /||; print; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

`-R`: List the ACLs of all files and directories recursively.

`-s`: Skip files that only have the base ACL entries (owner, group,  others).

```sh
getfacl -Rs .
```

```sh
getfacl --recursive --skip-base .
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:

```
getfacl --recursive --skip-base / 2>/dev/null | grep "file:" | cut -d" " -f3 | awk '{print "/"$1}'
```

returns:

```
/dev/snd/seq
/dev/snd/timer
/dev/dri/card0
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this googling the opposite; to find files with no ACLs set. This is what I ended up with (in case some other googler finds it)

```
ls --color=auto -lR | grep -v "\+ " | grep -v "^[.,a-z,1-9]" | grep -v "^$"
```

Apparently `ls -R` is faster than find (I have a kagillion files and each find command is taking me 2 hours).