# Store ACL's somewhere

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

This is an administration question.

For various reasons, one being misbehaving users, I set ACL's for common system programs (`write`, `mail`, etc..) forbidding their execution by certain users.

However, this information is too disperse: The only way to retrieve the set of "distinguished" users is to do a search for ACL'd files and read them manually.

Is there some ready-made solution that would allow me to keep them all in a single file or centralized somewhere? I realize I can make a script, or list them manually, but maybe there's something more clever. Maybe a way to find ACL'd files?

Answer (score 1):

Put the users all in one specific group, then make your ACLs prevent members of that group from executing the commands.

As for finding ACL'd files, check this previous question: [find files with ACLs set](https://superuser.com/questions/398448/find-files-with-acls-set)